# Clipping raster using a vector 's extent in GDAL

Tags: python, raster, gdal, vector

I am trying to take a raster (landsat_tm.img) and clip it to the spatial extent of the vector (clip.shp).  My problem is that the band 1 values are being copied for all 7 bands.

```
    #import modules
    import numpy, os, ogr, osr, sys
    import gdal,gdalconst
    from gdalconst import *
    gdal.UseExceptions()

    #set working directory
    os.chdir(r'Q:\Personal\Exercises')

    #set drivers
    raster_driver=gdal.GetDriverByName("HFA")
    raster_driver.Register()
    vector_driver=ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
    vector_driver.Register()

    #define data sources
    fn="landsat_tm.img"
    vector_fn='clip.shp'

    #open data source
    raster_ds= gdal.Open(fn,GA_ReadOnly)

    #check if raster exists
    if raster_ds is None:
        print "Couldn't open."
        sys.exit(1)

    #get basic image info
    bands=raster_ds.RasterCount
    cols= raster_ds.RasterXSize
    rows= raster_ds.RasterYSize

    #get basic info on image coordinate and pixel resolution
    geotransform= raster_ds.GetGeoTransform()
    originX= geotransform[0]
    originY= geotransform[3]
    pixelWidth= geotransform[1]
    pixelHeight= geotransform[5]

    #open vector data source and read in extent
    vector_ds= ogr.Open(vector_fn)
    vector_layer = vector_ds.GetLayer()
    x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = vector_layer.GetExtent()

    # Get vector x and y resolution info
    x_res = abs(int((x_max - x_min) / pixelWidth))
    y_res = abs(int((y_max - y_min) / pixelHeight))

    #get x and y offset
    xOffset=int((x_min - originX)/pixelWidth)
    yOffset=int((y_max- originY)/pixelHeight)

    #access bands in data source
    band= raster_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

    #transform image to array
    image_array=band.ReadAsArray(xOffset,yOffset,x_res,y_res)

    #create subset image
    subset=raster_driver.Create("subset.img", x_res, y_res, 7, GDT_Float32)

    #add data to blank subset image
    index = 0
    for i in range (bands):
        index = index + 1
        outband= subset.GetRasterBand (i + 1)
        outband.WriteArray(image_array, 0, 0)
        outband.FlushCache()
        outband.SetNoDataValue(-999)
        stats=outband.GetStatistics(0,1)

    #set geotransform
    transformation=[x_min, geotransform[1], geotransform[2], y_min,geotransform[4], geotransform[5]]
    subset.SetGeoTransform(transformation)

    #set projection
    subset.SetProjection(raster_ds.GetProjection())
    gdal.SetConfigOption("HFA_USE_RRD", "YES")

    #build pyramids
    subset.BuildOverviews(overviewlist=[2,4,8,16,32,64,128])
    subset= None
```

Update: For loop should look like this for anyone wondering.

```
    for i in range (raster_ds.RasterCount):
        i += 1
        inband = raster_ds.GetRasterBand(i)
        imgdata= inband.ReadAsArray(xOffset,yOffset,x_res,y_res).astype(numpy.float)
        subset_array= subset_ds.GetRasterBand(i)
        subset_array.WriteArray(imgdata, 0, 0)
        stats=subset_array.GetStatistics(0,1)
        subset_array.FlushCache()
        subset_array.SetNoDataValue(-999)
```

Answer (score 1):

This line gives you a hint: `ValueError: expected array of dim 2`.

This usually means that the data that you're writing doesn't have the right dimensions. You'd better inspect the variable `image_array` to check that it is a two dimensional array.

I'm not really familiar with how the previous functions work, you I can't help troubleshoot this. But do something like `print image_array.shape` to view the current shape of that array, and check that you're forming it right.

Answer (score 0):

The error is resulting from iterating through the bands and tryin to write all bands each time:

```
for i in range (bands):
    outband.WriteArray(image_array, 0, 0)
```

`image_array` contains all bands and is a numpy array with 3 dimensions. You need to slice it to the band you want to write to get a 2-dimensional array you can write into the band. i.e. `image_array[0, :, :]` is a 2D array containing all pixels from the first band.

Most probably you want something like this.

```
for i in range (bands):
    outband.WriteArray(image_array[i, :, :], 0, 0)
```

Comment: yes, you're right. All bands are writing information from the first band. So, even though I got the subset image to output, the values for all bands are the same.  When I tried your line of code, I got outband.WriteArray(image_array[i,:,:], 0, 0)
IndexError: too many indices for array